# Youtube iframe video is not working in UC Browser

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api, uc-browser

I am trying to play youtube videos using youtube iframe api on my web page. It is working in every browser I have tested. But in UC broswer, that's not the case.
When user play youtube video, error message is being shown: "Your browser does not currently recognize any of the video formats available.

[image]

First I thought, that it might be possible that UC Browser doesn't support HTML5. But that's not the case.

This is the code I am using to play youtube video:

```
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '160',
          width: '320',
          videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
      }
```

Is there any thing specific we need to do to make it play video in UC browser?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing you can do about this.  If YouTube doesn't support encodings for a particular platform, that's up to them.

Additionally, not all videos are encoded in all codecs and containers.